# How to derive $\exists$ Elimination rule in Enderton's system

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm trying to derive the following rule :

> from $α→β$, infer $(∃x)α→β$, provided that $x$ is not free in $β$

in the system of Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=Herbert%20Enderton_A%20Mathematical%20Introduction%20to%20Logic%20) (2nd - 2001).

The axioms are [see page 112] :

> The logical axioms are all generalizations of wffs of the following forms, where $x$ and $у$ are variables and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are wffs:
>
> 1. Tautologies;
> 2. $\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \alpha[x/t]$, where $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\alpha$;
> 3. $\forall x(\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \rightarrow (\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta)$;
> 4. $\alpha \rightarrow \forall x \alpha$, where $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$.

If the language includes equality, the usual axiom for it are added.

*Modus ponens* is the sole rule of inference.

---

What we can prove in Enderton's system is the following meta-theorem :

> if $\Gamma \vdash \alpha \rightarrow \beta$, and $x$ is not free in $\beta$ nor in any formula in $\Gamma$, then : $\Gamma \vdash \exists x \alpha \rightarrow \beta$.

*Proof* :

We have to start from :

*(1)* $\Gamma \vdash \alpha \rightarrow \beta$

*(2)* $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \beta \rightarrow \lnot \alpha$ --- from (1) and Taut, by *mp*

*(3)* $\lnot \beta$ --- assumed

*(4)* $\Gamma, \lnot \beta \vdash \lnot \alpha$.

Now, due to the proviso, we can apply the **Gen Th** to have :

*(5)* $\Gamma, \lnot \beta \vdash \forall x \lnot \alpha$

*(6)* $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \beta \rightarrow \forall x \lnot \alpha$ --- from (3) and (5), by *Deduction Theorem*

*(7)* $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \forall x \lnot \alpha \rightarrow \beta$ --- from (6) and Taut, by *mp*

> *(8)* $\Gamma \vdash \exists x \alpha \rightarrow \beta$ --- abbreviation.

From this theorem, under the same proviso, with $\Gamma = \emptyset$ we have :

> *(A)*   if $\vdash \alpha \rightarrow \beta$, then $\vdash \exists x \alpha \rightarrow \beta$.

---

*Note* : these rules are not stated in Enderton's book, but we can easily derive the last one from the theorem in **Example (Q3B)** [page 122] :

> $\vdash (\exists x \alpha \rightarrow \beta) \leftrightarrow \forall x(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$, provided that $x$ does not occur free in $\beta$.

*Proof :*

*(1)* $\vdash \alpha \rightarrow \beta$

*(2)* $\vdash \forall x(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ --- by **Generalization Theorem** [page 117] : if $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ and $x$ does not occur free in any formula in $\Gamma$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \varphi$, with $\Gamma = \emptyset$.

*(3)* $\vdash \exists x \alpha \rightarrow \beta$ --- by (Q3B).

In the same way, from the theorem of **Example (Q2A)** [page 121] :

> $\vdash (\alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta) \leftrightarrow \forall x(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$, provided that $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$,

we can prove the meta-theorem :

> *(B)*   if $\vdash \alpha \rightarrow \beta$, then $\vdash \alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta$,

with the same proviso.

Of course, we can deduce it from the "more general" meta-theorem :

> if $\Gamma \vdash \alpha \rightarrow \beta$, and $x$ is not free in $\alpha$ nor in any formula in $\Gamma$, then : $\Gamma \vdash \alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta$

which can easily be proved as the other one.

The rules *(A)* and *(B)* are the *Rules for the Universal and Existential Quantifiers* used by David Hilbert & Wilhelm Ackermann, *Principles of Mathematical Logic* (2nd ed - 1937; see english translation, page 70) and due to Paul Bernays (see footnote); they are used also by S.C.Kleene in his textbooks.

Comment: Re: "From $α→β$, infer $(∃x)α→β$, provided that $x$ is not free in $β.$"  Existential generalization need not be this complicated. You rarely see such considerations in mathematics textbooks, and for good reasons. For details, download my free proof-checking software at http://www.dcproof.com If there is sufficient interest, I can post excerpts from my user manual for discussion at the sci.math newsgroup.

Comment: @DanChristensen - in so-called *Hilbert-style proof system* (like Enderton's), this is simply the "equivalent" of the *Natutral Deduction* rule for $\exists$ Elimination.

Comment: I found the interplay between existential specification and universal generalization to be one of the most difficult problems to solve in my program: How to prohibit deriving $\exists y: \forall x\in S:R(x,y)$ from $\forall x\in S: \exists y: R(x,y)$ in some elegant, easy to explain fashion not too different from how mathematicians actually write proofs.

Comment: @DanChristensen - I'm not sure to understand the formulae; the first one looks like : $(∃y)(∀x)[x∈S \rightarrow R(x,y)]$. Is my "translation" the right one ? Or it is :  $(∃y)[(∀x)x∈S \rightarrow R(x,y)]$ ?. For the second one : $(∀x)[x∈S \rightarrow (∃y)R(x,y)]$ ...

Comment: You could translate it as: $\forall x:[x\in S \implies \exists y: R(x,y)].$ I'm just restricting the domain of the universal quantifier. I don't allow introduction of free variables by universal specification ($\forall$ Elimination).

Comment: @DanChristensen - Ok for the second one; but I've a doubt about the first also (see above). Thanks !

Comment: The first could be translated $\exists y: \forall x:[x\in S\implies R(x,y)].$

Comment: @DanChristensen - I'm not sure to understand what are you meaning with : "some elegant, easy to explain fashion". But we know that $\forall$ and $\exists$ do not "commute", i.e.$\forall x \exists y \nvDash \exists y \forall x$. Now your formula $∀x∈S:∃y:R(x,y)$ is $(∀x)[S(x)→(∃y)R(x,y)]$. From formula (Q2B) of Enderton [page 130] we have $⊢(α→∃yβ)↔∃y(α→β)$, if $y$ does not occur *free* in $\alpha$. Thus, your formula [where $\alpha$ is $S(x)$], is equivalent to $(∀x)(∃y)[S(x)→R(x,y)]$ and we know (see the "non-commute" issue above) that ... 1/2

Comment: ... we know that $(∀x)(∃y)[S(x)→R(x,y)] \nvDash (∃y)(∀x)[S(x)→R(x,y)]$. 2/2

Comment: I picked what I thought was the simplest translation. Also, my example is only a symptom of the problem. While it may work in this case, the rule cannot be simply that $\forall$ and $\exists$ do not commute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule

> from $α→β$, infer $(∃x)α→β$, provided that $x$ is not free in $β$,

without "constraint" on the *assumption* $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$, is **not** sound.

Let $\alpha := x = y$ and let $\beta := \forall x (x = y)$; the proviso that $x \notin FV(\beta)$ is satisfied.

If we apply the above rule, we get :

> $\exists x (x = y) \rightarrow \forall x (x = y)$.

But this is **not** *true* in a domain with more than one element.

Thus, we need the assumption in the form : $\Gamma \vdash \alpha \rightarrow \beta$, whit proviso that $x$ is not free in $β$ nor in any formula in $\Gamma$.

If we try to use in the "unconstrained" form, we are using it with $\Gamma = \{ α→β \}$, and in this case it is nor more true that $x$ is not free in any formula in $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works, and it's definitely not formal since I'm not listing the tautologies properly, but maybe it'll get you thinking.

```
assumption   (1) (α→β) 

hypothesis   (2) (∃x)α 

axiom 4      (3) [(α→β)→∀x(α→β)]

MP (1), (3)  (4) ∀x(α→β)

axiom 3      (5) [∀x(α→β)→(∀xα→∀xβ)]

MP (5), (4)  (6) (∀xα→∀xβ)

MP, Taut, (6) (7) (¬∀xβ→¬∀xα)  (the tautology is CCpqCNqNp in Polish notation)

MP, Taut, (7) (8) (¬¬∀xβ $\lor$ ¬∀xα) (the tautology is CCpqANpq)

MP, Taut, (8) (9)  (¬¬∀xβ $\lor$ ¬∀x¬¬α) (the tautology is CANNpqANNpNNq)

Def. of ∃     (10) (¬¬∀xβ $\lor$ ∃x¬α)

MP twice, Taut, 10, 2  (11) ¬¬∀xβ (the tautology is CANNpNqCqNNp)

MP Taut, 11 (12) ∀xβ (the tautology is CNNpp)

axiom 2     (13) ∀xα→α[x/t]

MP, 13, 12  (14) β

DT 2-14      (15) ((∃x)α→β)
```

Comment: I think there is a mistake : the proviso of the (to be verified) rule is : in the assumption $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$, $x$ is **not** free in $\beta$ ... but it may be free in $\alpha$. In your step 3, you applied axiom n°4 in the form : $(\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \rightarrow \forall x(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ and this needs that $x$ is **not** free in $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$.